"This app, which is made with Flutter, keeps going into ultra power-saving mode on my Galaxy
I've developed an app with Flutter, and I'm experiencing this issue only on Galaxy devices.

Symptoms:

After running the app for several minutes to a few hours, a message appears saying, "The A app is sending notifications or causing the smartphone to slow down, resulting in increased battery consumption, so it will be switched to ultra power-saving mode." Along with this message, the home widget disappears. Tapping on the notification displays a [Delete app] button, prompting for deletion my app.
In reality, the app doesn't send any notifications or perform background tasks. The home widget merely displays data sent by the app when it's in the foreground.

Investigations:

Since adding background execution and requesting battery usage permissions didn't resolve the issue, I've conducted the following investigations:

Created a new project with the same package name (com.abc.name) and ran it with a blank page. After leaving it idle for some time, the same notification appeared.

Changed the package name in the existing app from com.abc.name to com.abc.name2. Then, registered the login procedures for com.abc.name2 on Google Cloud. After these changes, the issue didn't occur.



Temporary Solution:

Simply changing the package name from com.abc.name to com.abc.name2 in the existing project resolves the issue.

Seeking Advice:

However, changing the package name prevents updates to the existing app. Even in a new project with the same package name, the issue persists. I'm seeking advice on identifying the root cause of this problem.
Thank you.

The issue you're encountering with your Flutter app on Galaxy devices, which is flagged for increased battery consumption and prompts users to delete the app, appears to be related to Samsung's device-specific battery optimization and power management policies. Here are several steps and considerations to help identify and potentially resolve the root cause:
1. Samsung's Battery Optimization Policies
Samsung devices are known for aggressive battery optimization features, which can sometimes misinterpret app behaviour as problematic. These features include:

App optimization: Samsung devices attempt to minimize background activity to save battery life.
Background activity restrictions: Even apps that do not run background tasks might be flagged due to certain triggers, such as excessive foreground usage or perceived system resource consumption.

2. Review App Permissions and Usage
Ensure that your app's permissions and usage patterns comply with best practices to avoid unnecessary battery consumption. This includes:

Minimizing foreground activity: Ensure that your app does not inadvertently perform heavy tasks or excessive redraws while in the foreground.
Battery usage permissions: Even if requested, evaluate if the permissions are set correctly and whether they are necessary.

3. Testing with Different Package Names
The fact that changing the package name resolves the issue suggests a potential problem with how Samsung's software treats the original package name:

Cached Policies: Samsung's optimization policies may have cached settings for the specific package name com.abc.name.
Reputation: If the original package name has been flagged due to previous usage or reports, it might continue to trigger the warning.

4. Using Manifest Settings to Override Optimizations
You can try to use specific settings in your AndroidManifest.xml to request exemptions from battery optimization:
<application
    android:label="YourApp"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
    
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
    
    <receiver android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>

5. Samsung Developer Support
Given the specificity of the issue to Samsung devices, reaching out to Samsung's developer support may provide insights. Samsung has a developer support system that can help with device-specific issues.

Samsung Developer Support: Samsung Developers

6. Temporary Solutions and Workarounds
While a permanent solution is being found, consider the following temporary measures:

User Instructions: Inform your users how to manually disable battery optimization for your app through device settings.
Package Name Change: Although not ideal, continuing to use a different package name (com.abc.name2) might be necessary if no other solution is viable.


Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
